# What Sheri S. Tepper novel includes a prophet and a resulting religion?

Tags: story-identification, novel

What Sheri S. Tepper book includes a prophet saying “Don’t let them mess with your head” *and* a resulting religion which forbids haircuts?

Answer (score 15):

I believe you are recalling [*Raising the Stones*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1341) (1990). You haven't got the quote completely correct though:

> "Well," she said in a shaky voice when they were left alone. The three of them were looking at her as though she were something doubtful and possibly dangerous. She looked back, thinking they were the dangerous ones, the whole ensemble of them: three stocky white-tuniced figures, each tunic diagonally slashed by a wide purple belt with a zettle tucked into it; three dark, round faces turned toward her under three immaculate and identically folded white turbans; three triangles of ochre hair showing over three unwrinkled brows; three pairs of pale yellow, very glittery eyes, which seemed to be examining her soul. Under those turbans, the hair would be long enough to sit on, but done up in tight braids. **In obedience to the prophetess's command, High Baidee did not cut their hair. The prophetess had said, "Do not let people fool with your heads," and heads included hair.** The Scrutators had ruled, however, that faces were distinct from heads, and the male Baidee were not bearded.

Comment: Chasing down a quote made me slow, but it's an exact quote not a paraphrase so I'm going to leave it here.

Answer (score 12):

I believe this is Sheri S. Tepper's ***[Arbai](https://www.goodreads.com/series/51879-arbai)*** trilogy.

- Book 1: *[Grass](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/104342)* (1989)
- Book 2: *[Raising the Stones](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/104348.Raising_the_Stones)* (1990)
- Book 3: *[Sideshow](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/89589.Sideshow)* (1992)

From [the Little Red Reviewer's review](https://littleredreviewer.wordpress.com/2017/03/31/rereading-sheri-s-teppers-raising-the-stones/) of *Raising the Stones*:

> Another fun little parallel I noticed is how the novels in this loose trilogy are spaced out, time wise. **This novel takes place at least a thousand years after Grass.  During those thousand years, the Baidee took what their prophet said and twisted it all over the place, interpreting “don’t let people mess with your head” as a ruling that hair should not be cut,** and no one should attempt to tell anyone else what to think – and neither of those are anything close to what she meant. Eventually, I’ll get around to the third book in the series, SideShow, (which jumps in time maybe another thousand years?) where what was seen as good and helpful, or at least harmless, in Raising the Stones is suddenly seen as the most horrible thing in the universe.  Time heals all, but the passage of time really screws with communication! What makes us need to read so far between the lines that we lose sight of the original message?